# How to set discr in Nelmio Alice fixture generator

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, fixtures

I have this entity:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="person")
 * @ORM\InheritanceType("JOINED")
 * @ORM\DiscriminatorColumn(name="discr", type="string")
 * @ORM\DiscriminatorMap({
 *     "natural" = "NaturalPerson",
 *     "legal" = "LegalPerson"
 * })
 * @Gedmo\SoftDeleteable(fieldName="deletedAt", timeAware=false)
 */
class Person {
    use IdentifiedAutogeneratedEntityTrait;

    /**
     * Hook timestampable behavior
     * updates createdAt, updatedAt fields
     */
    use TimestampableEntity;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="description", type="string", length=250, nullable=false)
     */
    protected $description;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="contact_person", type="string", length=250, nullable=true)
     */
    protected $contact_person;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="person_type", type="integer", nullable=false)
     */
    protected $person_type = 1;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Orders", mappedBy="person")
     * */
    protected $orders;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="deletedAt", type="datetime", nullable=true)
     */
    protected $deletedAt;

}
```

And I'm using Doctrine Table Inheritance here so I want to make a test suite using `Nelmio Alice` for that entity, how I should deal with `discr` column? I mean how I say to Alice which type to use? I have tried this:

```
FrontendBundle\Entity\Person:
    Person{1..10}:
        description: <text(15)>
        contact_person: <text(75)>
        person_type: <randomElement(array('1','2'))>
        discr: <randomElement(array('natural','legal'))>
```

But does not work since `discr` isn't a column on `Person` entity, any advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's an interesting edge case. I see two potential solutions:

1. you add a property discr so alice can set it, but I don't know if that will make doctrine happy or not.
2. create the two different types of entity yourself, i.e.

   ```
   FrontendBundle\Entity\NaturalPerson:
       Person{1..5}:
           description: <text(15)>
           contact_person: <text(75)>
           person_type: <randomElement(array('1','2'))>

   FrontendBundle\Entity\LegalPerson:
       Person{6..10}:
           description: <text(15)>
           contact_person: <text(75)>
           person_type: <randomElement(array('1','2'))>
   ```

   Or to keep it short and avoid duplication you can use inheritance:

   ```
   FrontendBundle\Entity\Person:
       person (template):
           description: <text(15)>
           contact_person: <text(75)>
           person_type: <randomElement(array('1','2'))>

   FrontendBundle\Entity\NaturalPerson:
       Person{1..5} (extends person):

   FrontendBundle\Entity\LegalPerson:
       Person{6..10} (extends person):
   ```

If none of these works please report it on github so we can look at finding a solution.

Comment: well I have as your first solution now but I can't test it due to [this problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26050825/setting-up-parameter-as-array-in-nelmio-alice-fixture-generator) can you take a look to that post and try to find what I'm doing wrong? After solve that one I'll keep continue tryng this one, could you please?

Comment: Hi @Seldaek I confirm the second approach did the job and I got the expected result, thanks I'll write a small fix on docs as you suggested and try to add this part. Can you take a look to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26104851/how-to-pass-faker-data-result-to-a-custom-function) post too? It's another one interesting and it's not documented tough