# How to pass faker data result to a custom function

Tags: php, symfony, fixtures, faker

I'm using [PhoneNumberBundle](https://github.com/misd-service-development/phone-number-bundle) for validates phone number on my application. I'm using also [NelmioAliceBundle](https://github.com/nelmio/alice) together with [AliceFixtureBundle](https://github.com/h4cc/AliceFixturesBundle). Having that as start point I'm writing a fixture for a entity that has a `PhoneNumberBundle` assert for validate the phone number. Here is a snippet of that file:

```
/**
 * @AssertPhoneNumber(defaultRegion="VE")
 * @ORM\Column(name="phone", type="phone_number", length=11)
 */
protected $phone;
```

I don't know how to use external libraries on the fixture itself so the only solution I see if to write my own faker and return the well formated number phone and pass back to the fixture. Then I did this:

**TananeFakerProvider.php**

```
class TananeFakerProvider {

    public function formatPhoneNumber($fakePhoneNumber)
    {
        return $this->container->get('libphonenumber.phone_number_util')->parse($fakePhoneNumber);
    }

}
```

**services.yml**

```
services:
    tanane.faker.provider:
        class: CommonBundle\Tools\TananeFakerProvider
        arguments: ["@service_container"]
        tags:
            -  { name: h4cc_alice_fixtures.provider }
```

And finally **Orders.yml** (the fixture):

```
FrontendBundle\Entity\Orders:
    Orders{1..50}:
        nickname: <text(15)>
        # trying to pass the fake number back to the custom faker
        phone: <formatPhoneNumber(phoneNumber())>
        email: <companyEmail()>
        fiscal_address: <address()>
        shipping_address: <address()>
        shipping_from: <randomElement(array('MRW','DOMESA', 'ZOOM'))>
        payment_type: @PaymentType*
        order_amount: <randomFloat(2)>
        bank: @Bank*
        transaction: <randomNumber()>
        comments: <sentence(15)>
        secure: <boolean(35)>
        person: <randomElement(array(@Natural*, @Legal*))> 
        status: @OrderStatus*
```

But I got this error:

> [Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\ContextErrorException]   Notice:
>   Use of undefined constant phoneNumber - assumed 'phoneNumber' in
>   /var/www/html/vendor/nelmio/alice/src/Nelmio/Alice/Loader/Base.php(630)
>   : eval()'d code line 1

So I'm passing the value in the wrong way, could any give me some help on this? Or maybe give me another idea in how to achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(Settled on github, but for posterity here is a copy)

You can use the following in Alice 1.x:

```
FrontendBundle\Entity\Orders:
    Orders{1..50}:
        nickname: <text(15)>
        # trying to pass the fake number back to the custom faker
        phone: <formatPhoneNumber($this->fake('phoneNumber'))>
```

And this in the 2.x line:

```
FrontendBundle\Entity\Orders:
    Orders{1..50}:
        nickname: <text(15)>
        # trying to pass the fake number back to the custom faker
        phone: <formatPhoneNumber($fake('phoneNumber'))>
```

Answer (score 3):

As an alternative you can pass a Faker Provider object as a second parameter when instantiating a Nelmio/Alice/Fixtures/Loader class.

1.- Create a Provider Class

```
class MyCustomFakeProvider
{
    public function tell_me_something()
    {
        return 'something';
    }
}
```

2.-

```
use Nelmio\Alice\Fixtures\Loader;

use Doctrine\Common\DataFixtures\AbstractFixture;
use Doctrine\Common\DataFixtures\OrderedFixtureInterface;

class ExampleDataLoader extends AbstractFixture implements OrderedFixtureInterface
{
    public function loadMyDataFixtures() {       

        $myCustomFakeProvider = new MyCustomFakeProvider();
        $loader = new Loader('es_ES', $myCustomFakeProvider);
        $objects = $loader->load(__DIR__ . '/example.yml');

        $persister = new \Nelmio\Alice\Persister\Doctrine($manager);
        $persister->persist($objects);
```

3.- Finally create a example.yml file (at the same level than the Loader class in this case) with some data and a custom call to tell_me_something()

```
AppBundle\Entity\Example:
    examples_1{1..101}:
    title: <tell_me_something()> # MY CUSTOM METHOD
    description: <sentence()>
```