# how to set roles datafixtures in hautelook alicebundle?

Tags: php, symfony, fosuserbundle, nelmio-alice, alice-fixtures

I'm having a hard time to fix this problem by adding roles in datafixtures using hautelook bundle. I create a provider that will add a roles to the fixtures

```
<?php

namespace AdminBundle\DataFixtures\Faker\Provider;
use AppBundle\Entity\AdminUserTypes;

class Roles
{
    public function roleAdvocate(){

        return ['ROLE_ADMIN', 'ROLE_ADVOCATE'];
    }
}
```

in my datafixtures yml i have this code

```
AppBundle\Entity\AdminUser:
    adminuser_101:
        username: '<username()>'
        email: '<email()>'
        adminUserType: 2
        enabled: true
        roles: '<roleAdvocate()>'
```

when the time the I run the phpunit, i always get this result error from roles

```
  Warning: in_array() expects parameter 2 to be array, null given
```

I have no idea now on how to fix it. Even I tweak the array. I get an error. I have this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26050825/setting-up-parameter-as-array-in-nelmio-alice-fixture-generator) but it doesn't work either. same result

Comment: can you please show your entity code?

Comment: @AlessandroMinoccheri I already get the answer. I will answer it. This can help to everyone. almost one day to solve this problem.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In my project. I create another Entity called     **AdminUser Entity**. This entity I inherit the abstract class User

```
class AdminUser extends User
```

Then I realize I forgot to add this method to inherit the parents constructor.

```
 public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply define $roles like that in your AdminUser entity :

```
/**
 * @var array
 */
protected $roles = [];
```

By default $roles is null and can't be used as an array.

Answer (score 1):

Syntax for arrays with AliceBundle uses []

So this should work:

`AppBundle\Entity\AdminUser:
    adminuser_101:
        username: '<username()>'
        email: '<email()>'
        adminUserType: 2
        enabled: true
        roles: ['<roleAdvocate()>']`